# Implement custom connector to in-house applications

Tags: onelogin

I am trying to figure out how custom connectors work or if it's the correct solution. Basically the company I work at wants to implement a "login using OneLogin" to our in-house applications and we have MFA enabled. I tried the API route but it requires the user to enter the MFA code every time they want to log in, which is great for security but users want simple solution. So I was suggested to look into custom connectors by our IT folks. I've read through the "Building Custom Connectors" documentation at https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202361830-Building-Custom-Connectors. But I was trying to figure out a way to just navigate the user to the OneLogin login portal and then redirect back to which ever in-house application the user is trying log into.

If anyone has any suggestions or an idea on how to best implement this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You really need to implement SAML as it's a stardard designed to do exactly your use case (including MFA if configured for that account and/or application)

Check out https://developers.onelogin.com/saml for more information.

Comment: Awesome! I'll look into it and see if I can get it working. Do I have to add our in-house applications into your guys public catalog or is there a place where I can add it into our private catalog?

Comment: No need to have the application in our catalog- You can configure a Generic SAML application in your account (and give it a name and and Icon)

Comment: Would you happen to have instructions on how to create a generic SAML application? In the link you provide, it has instructions on how to add it to the OneLogin catalog but couldn't find anything on creating in it in our account. Also, I don't have admin access in our account so I have to tell the IT folks what needs to be done.

Comment: You're still going to want to go through steps 1 & 2 in the link above (get a dev account)

Once you have your own account you won't have to go through your IT dept, and can just test on your own. 

From there you'll be able to "Add an application" and just search for "OneLogin SAML" - This will show all the SAML test connectors 

But really the first step is to implement SAML in your app (once you have a dev account). Depending on what type of SAML capabilities you add, this will determine which SAML connector you'll want to use.

Comment: Oh yeah, details on the test connector configuration can be found here:

https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector

Comment: Awesome! Got a dev one working with my test app. Now the only question I have is, when I'm having the IT folks create one on the real domain would they be using the SAML test connectors or is there a production one I should have them use to create the SAML app?

Comment: If you expect folks outside your company to use this application, contact OneLogin support and they'll be happy to set up an official connector in their catalog.

If not, you'll be fine setting up yet another test connector for your production instance.